# Modify data before being fetched using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario where I am being returned a set of times, but would like to reformat them, then subtract them both to get a new time object and push that object to my list before I return.

I've tried the following in my action but no luck. I need to iterate through the entire list.

Output.json

```
{
    "tatt": {
        "tmst": "2017-03-19T20:18:36",
        "errCd": "0",
        "errNm": null,
        "eta": [{

            "prdt": "2017-03-19T20:18:19",
            "arrT": "2017-03-19T20:24:19",

        }, {

            "prdt": "2017-03-19T20:18:06",
            "arrT": "2017-03-19T20:25:06",

        }, {

            "prdt": "2017-03-19T20:17:54",
            "arrT": "2017-03-19T20:28:54",

        }]
    }
}
```

action.js

```
import axios from "axios";

function transformDateFormat(json) {

    const arrival = {
        ...json,
        date: json.data.ctatt.eta[0].arrT.substring(json.data.ctatt.eta[0].arrT.indexOf("T") + 1)   
    }
    console.log(arrival)
    return arrival;
}

export const fetchTime = () => {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    axios.get('/data/output.json')
      .then(transformDateFormat)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_FULFILLED", payload: response.data.ctatt.eta})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

Logic to create new time;

```
var date1 = "2017-03-18T21:28:53"; 
var date2 = "2017-03-18T21:27:53"; 

date1 = date1.substring(date1.indexOf("T") + 1);
date2 = date2.substring(date2.indexOf("T") + 1);

function parseTime(s) {
   var c = s.split(':');
   return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

var minutes = parseTime(date1) - parseTime(date2);
console.log(minutes + " min")
```

**UPDATE:**

So I was able to solve this, but only after it's being returned through my component and I am doing the manipulation there. Not sure if this is the right way to go about it...Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Your reducer is not a real reducer, it's a action. Do the transform logic in the real reducer.

Comment: doh, correct. sorry, long day